# Is it possible to set state in Immer's produce()?

Tags: reactjs, immutability

#### Now

```
await this.setState(produce(this.state, (draft) => {
    draft.item.is_loading = true;
}));
this.setState(await produce(this.state, async (draft) => {
    // is_loading is true now.
    const name = await get_name();
    draft.item.name = name;
    draft.item.is_loading = false;
}));
```

#### Expected

```
this.setState(await produce(this.state, async (draft) => {
    let name;

    draft.item.is_loading = true;

    // set state here first.

    name = await get_name();
    draft.item.name = name;
    draft.item.is_loading = false;
}));
```

I want to set state in the middle of calling `produce()`. Is It possible? If there's any good idea, please let me know. Thanks. :D

That's because I think connecting two chunks together is more readable. Especially when I can reuse variable declared in the former. It can looks quite trivial, but the more complex a source code becomes, the more unnatural it becomes to me.

Comment: I don't believe so. Could you add *why* you want to do this?